# Was bedeutet „sogar mit jdm. sein“?

Tags: meaning, phrase

> Die zweite [Tochter] ist sogar mit einem Doktor. Der wird sie einmal heiraten.

„Sogar mit jdm. sein“ beschreibt anscheinend eine Beziehung. Was für eine Beziehung ist es? Ist es symmetrisch? D.h: ist der Doktor zwangsläufig mit der zweiten Tochter sogar?

**Edit**: Der Kontext:

> Die erste ist verheiratet, ich glaub, mit a Chauffeur. 
>   Die zweite ist sogar mit einem Doktor. 
>   Der wird sie einmal heiraten.

Anscheinend sind sie noch nicht verheiratet, weil sie einmal heiraten werden.

Comment: That sentence sounds incomplete. Can you maybe quote the sentence that precedes this one? Usually the phrase is "mit jemandem *zusammen* sein". The "sogar" only signifies that this is somehow more than what was expected. In English you'd probably use "even". It's not part of the idiom in any case.

Comment: @Oliver: It's from a song by Georg Kreisler. See [the full text to Der General](http://www.hjp.at/lyrics/georg_kreisler/der_general.html).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that _sogar_ isn't important! I didn't realise that.

Comment: Achso! The preceding sentence was quite important: "Die erste ist verheiratet, ich glaub, mit a Chauffeur". I'll edit the question.

Comment: Where did you pick that up, actually?

Comment: Rejected edit - it's a citation!

Comment: @ladybug: It's from [Georg Kreisler's Der General](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdxuEbA6-rU). See comment above.

Comment: One of many examples: http://bibeltext.com/isaiah/41-10.htm

Answer (score 10):

> Ist der Doktor zwangsläufig mit der zweiten Tochter sogar?

Die Wendung ist "mit jemandem sein" (ohne 'sogar').

Der Satz ist sehr ungewöhnlich, und im Alltag kaum so zu hören. Man darf aber annehmen, dass hier "zusammen sein" gemeint ist. Also etwa "in einer festen Beziehung sein". In diesem Falle ist es eine Beziehung zwischen der zweiten Tochter und dem Doktor.

Ein gutes Beispiel für ein [Zeugma](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_%28Sprache%29).

Comment: +1 für den Hinweis auf ein Zeugma.

Comment: Man kann ebenso das "zusammen" als redundant, aber nun einmal die heute übliche Formulierung auffassen. http://bibeltext.com/isaiah/41-10.htm

Answer (score 6):

In diesem Beispiel wird ein wesentlicher Teil des Satzes weggelassen. Es  fehlt das Adverb, das notwendig ist, um zu verstehen, was die Tochter "ist".

> Die zweite [Tochter] ist sogar mit einem Doktor ***verlobt***. Der wird sie einmal heiraten.

Die ist im vorliegenden Fall sicher ein stilistisches Mittel, um den eigentlichen Sachverhalt offen zu lassen oder zu verschleiern. Man hat es ja nicht ausgesprochen, also hat man auch nichts Falsches gesagt. Diese Art etwas zu sagen, aber nicht auszusprechen, ist ein Element der hohen Kunst des Tratsches.

Answer (score 6):

Für mich war der Satz auch ohne Kontext durchaus verständlich: *mit jemandem sein* bedeutet hier eine feste Beziehung (mit Aussicht auf Hochzeit, wie der nächste Satz sagt), das *sogar* bezieht sich auf den Status des Doktors. Der Sprecher bringt also seinen Wohlgefallen darüber zum Ausdruck, dass die Tochter (scheinbar) Aussicht auf Verheiratung hat – und das *sogar* mit einem Doktor (was hohen Status verspricht).

Comment: Ich fand das "mit jemandem sein" auch recht eindeutig...

Answer (score 3):

Ich kenne eine solche Formulierung nur als altertümliche Redewendung, bei der der genaue Beziehungsstatus offengelassen wird. Früher, so gegen damals, war ein lockeres Beziehungsleben nicht schicksam. Da sich zwei Menschen aber auch früher mal erst kennenlernen mussten, bevor sie sich verlobten, wurde dieser "Makel" nicht ausgesprochen.